# How to perform a "left join" in Redis?

Tags: join, redis, node-redis

Say I have a structure similar to reddit or stack overflow.

e.g. assuming that i have a json structure like

```
posts = [{id: 1, title: "foo", pages: 300}, {id: 2, title: "bar", pages: 300}]

votes = [{user_id: 1, post_id: 1, vote: "upvote"}]
```

how can i get a result similar to this (getting a post and attaching the users vote for this item, assuming it is known that the user_id is 1):

```
posts = [{id: 1, title: "foo", pages:300, vote: "upvote"}]
```

currently i am using an sql left outer join, but am trying to implement this using redis. i'm just having a hard time wrapping my mind around how to express this effectively in redis.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the votes as a sorted set per user (with e.g. a score 1 for up and a score -1 for down):

```
# Register upvote for post 1
ZADD votes:user:1 1 1
# Register downvote for post 2
ZADD votes:user:1 -1 2
```

Fetching user `1`:s vote for post `1`:

```
ZSCORE votes:user:1 1
# => "1"
```

If you need to reference the votes the other direction (all votes for a given post) you could simply keep a similar set, e.g. `votes:post:1`, with the votes for that post. Or if you just need to keep track of the accumulated score, just keep a counter.